# Function in Python gives error message

Tags: python, function

I am learning Python and I am reading the "Think Python" and doing some simple exercises included in the book.

I am asked "Define a new function called do_four that takes a function object and a value and calls the function four times, passing the value as a parameter."

I am trying to compose this function with one statement by calling a function already defined called do_twice() and test it with a function called print_double(). Here is the code:

```
def do_twice(f, x): 
    f(x) 
    f(x)

def do_four(f, v):
    do_twice(do_twice(f, v), v)

def print_twice(s): 
    print s
    print s

s = 'abc'

do_four(print_twice, s)
```

This code produces an error:

```
abc
abc
abc
abc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-95b513e5e0ee> in <module>()
----> 1 do_four(print_twice, s)

<ipython-input-40-100f8587f50a> in do_four(f, v)
      1 def do_four(f, v):
----> 2     do_twice(do_twice(f, v), v)

<ipython-input-38-7143620502ce> in do_twice(f, x)
      1 def do_twice(f, x):
----> 2     f(x)
      3     f(x)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

In trying to understand what is happening I tried to construct a Stack Diagram as described in the book. Here it is:

[image]

Could you explain the error message and comment on the Stack Diagram?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do_twice` gets a function on the first argument, and doesn't return anything. So there is no reason to pass `do_twice` the result of `do_twice`. You need to pass it `a function`.

This would do what you meant:

```
def do_four(f, v):
    do_twice(f, v)
    do_twice(f, v)
```

Very similar to how you defined `do_twice` by `f`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> do_twice(do_twice(f, v), v)
>          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Slightly rewritten:

```
result = do_twice(f, v)
do_twice(result, v)
```

You're passing the return value of `do_twice(...)` as the first parameter to `do_twice(...)`. That parameter is supposed to be a function object. `do_twice` does not *return* anything, so `result` is `None`, which you're passing instead of the expected function object.

There's no point in nesting the two `do_twice` in any way here.